# Replace line with empty line if certain character does'nt exist

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I would like a Replace expression that matches all lines containing **.function_call** and replace those lines with **empty lines**

However if that line has **=** in it, do nothing. 
For example 
    **int i = .function_call** should be left without adjustment.

I have no experience with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio -> Edit -> Find and Replace -> Replace in files

Find what: `^[^=]*\.function_call.*$`

Leave the `Replace with` box empty, and make sure you have the `Use` box checked and Regular Expressions selected.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this as the pattern:

```
^[\s\S-[=]]*\.function_call.*$
```

And replace it with `\n`.

Comment: Are you referring to the Visual Studio find and replace editing tool or you want to write some code to do it?